# My program exits my FOR loops before the conditions are met

Tags: c, for-loop

The program just breaks when I have two or more FOR loops one after another.

The program was supposed to generate 20 random numbers inside an ARRAY of 20 numbers and then separate the odd ones from the even ones into two different arrays, one for odd numbers, and one for even numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(){
    srand(time (NULL));

    int vector[20];
    int vectoreven[20];
    int vectorodd[20];
    int c = 0;

    for(c = 0;c <= 19;c = c+1){
        vector[c] = rand()%100;
    }
    c = 0;

    for(c = 0;c <= 19; c = c+1){
        printf("\nVector %d = %d", c, vector[c]);
    }
    c = 0;

    for(int d = 0;d <= 19; d = d+1){
        if(vector[d]%2 == 0){
                vectoreven[d] = vector[d];
                printf("\nVector even %d = {%d}", d, 
vectoreven[d]);
        }else if(vector[d]%2 != 0){
            vectorodd[d] = vector[d];
            printf("\nVector odd %d = I%dI", d, vectorodd[d]);
        }

    }
}
```

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZhNU.png)

Comment: Please use the title to explain the *technical problem* you're having.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use separate index variables for the arrays you're writing to than the array you're iterating over. This way you'll fill each array sequentially. Your method leaves lots of unfilled elements in the middle of the arrays, with no way to tell which these are.

```
int even_index = 0;
int odd_index = 0;

for (int d = 0; d < 20; d++) {
    if (vector[d] % 2 == 0) {
        vectoreven[even_index++] = vector[d];
    } else
        vectorodd[odd_index++] = vector[d];
    }
}
```